# Requesting specific data returns all the associated entities without using the Include()

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I am creating a simple web API (MVC) and I am currently using Entity Framework Code First approach. I have the following entities:

Authors, Courses, Institutions

I have set up a relationship in such a way that an author can have N number of courses and N number of institutions. I am writing the following method on the API:

```
public class PlutoController : ApiController
{
    private readonly PlutoDbContext _context;

    public PlutoController()
    {
        _context = new PlutoDbContext();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult GetAuthors()
    {
        var authors = _context.Authors
            .Where(a => a.AuthorID == 1).ToList();

        return Ok(authors);
    }
}
```

However, a call to the api returns authors and its associated courses and institutions.

```
[
{
    "Courses": [
        {
            "CourseSections": [],
            "Tags": [],
            "CourseID": 1,
            "AuthorID": 1,
            "Title": "C# Advanced",
            "Description": "C# Advanced Description",
            "Price": 69,
            "LevelString": "Advanced",
            "Level": 3
        },
        {
            "CourseSections": [],
            "Tags": [],
            "CourseID": 2,
            "AuthorID": 1,
            "Title": "C# Intermediate",
            "Description": "C# Intermediate Description",
            "Price": 49,
            "LevelString": "Intermediate",
            "Level": 2
        },
        {
            "CourseSections": [],
            "Tags": [],
            "CourseID": 3,
            "AuthorID": 1,
            "Title": "Clean Code",
            "Description": "Clean Code Description",
            "Price": 99,
            "LevelString": "Intermediate",
            "Level": 2
        }
    ],
    "Institution": [
        {
            "InstitutionId": 1,
            "AuthorId": 1,
            "InstitutionName": "University of Windsor"
        },
        {
            "InstitutionId": 2,
            "AuthorId": 1,
            "InstitutionName": "Boston University"
        },
        {
            "InstitutionId": 4,
            "AuthorId": 1,
            "InstitutionName": "Arizona State University"
        }
    ],
    "AuthorID": 1,
    "Name": "Bill Gates"
}]
```

In this, i can see that we are doing some eager loading which is not what i want. How do i just get only the author details?

Here are my generated models: 
Author

```
namespace PlutoAPI.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class Authors
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Authors()
        {
            Institution = new HashSet<Institution>();
            Courses = new HashSet<Courses>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int AuthorID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Institution> Institution { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Courses> Courses { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Courses:

```
namespace PlutoAPI.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    public partial class Courses
    {
        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
        public Courses()
        {
            CourseSections = new HashSet<CourseSections>();
            Tags = new HashSet<Tags>();
        }

        [Key]
        public int CourseID { get; set; }

        public int AuthorID { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(255)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(8000)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public short Price { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string LevelString { get; set; }

        public byte Level { get; set; }

        public virtual Authors Authors { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<CourseSections> CourseSections { get; set; }

        [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
        public virtual ICollection<Tags> Tags { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Institution

```
namespace PlutoAPI.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Data.Entity.Spatial;

    [Table("Institution")]
    public partial class Institution
    {
        public int InstitutionId { get; set; }

        public int? AuthorId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(50)]
        public string InstitutionName { get; set; }

        public virtual Authors Authors { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I presume [`LazyLoadingEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.infrastructure.dbcontextconfiguration.lazyloadingenabled?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) is set to true on your context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problem you are having is LazyLoading (not eager loading). To disable it.

```
public partial class YourDBContext : DbContext
{
    public YourDBContext(): base("name=YourDBContext")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked for me!! Thanks :) but I don't understand how is this not eager loading. Doesn't eager loading mean loading all the entities in one query?

Comment: Eager loading means loading related entities at the time load the main entity. But you need to use Include() to do that. In your case, since you don't use it, it doesn't load related entities when you ToList(). However, when you "return" it, the serializer start accessing those properties and EF start loading those properties.